# Spark - Prediction Probability API (predict_proba)

Tags: apache-spark

Does Apache Spark provide an API to get a decision tree's prediction probability similar to scikit-learn's predict_proba function (i.e., decision_tree.predict_proba(X))?

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for this myself. I almost hacked up a solution when I noticed the api has the functionality in a very awkward way (at least for the `LogisticRegressionModel`):

You clear the threshold (with `clearThreshold()`). That way the predict function doesn't return the label, but the underlying value.

[Java docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/classification/LogisticRegressionModel.html#clearThreshold()) say this:

> public LogisticRegressionModel clearThreshold()
>   :: Experimental :: Clears the threshold so that predict will output raw prediction scores.

FYI: the returned values are between 0. and 1., the default threshold value is .5, so you can easily assess what you want to set your threshold to.